# Regex to capture: word {word} word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture: word {word} word.

I have the following regex: `\S*\s\{.*?\}\S[^{\s]*`

It actually captures this pattern, but it also captures word {word}. See: https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/6

How to fix it to only capture: word {word} word ?

Thank you very much in advance for all the people who help.

Comment: Is `"[^{s]"` meant to be `"[^{\s]"` (ie whitespace, not a literal `"s"`)

Comment: Sorry, I fix it. In fact, another user edit because I forgot `` to regex. It was worse.. LOL

Comment: The range `A-z` matches more characters than only letters. I suugest you to have a look at an ASCII table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: `\w+\s+\{\w+\}\s+\w+`

[See explanation at regex101...](https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/7)

[image]

[Here you can visualize your regular expression...](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cw%2B%5Cs%2B%5C%7B%5Cw%2B%5C%7D%5Cs%2B%5Cw%2B)

Comment: Another question: https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/8. Is possible to capture test2 {test} test3 too?

Comment: I can think only to the following way:
https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/10
So you catch it all in one, and create a function with what you can disassemble it.

Comment: Thank you @Norbert Incze, I'll do that. I have another issue. It's about break lines. Can you help please? Look: https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/11 (I changed \w to [A-zÀ-ú] because my language has a lot of accented words, so \w not working correctly)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/16, to this you can add your special characters too, as I added mine.

Comment: Thank you man! You are a badass! haha You help me in this other questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495115/regex-get-only-sequence-of-word-word-word-word-word-but-not-two-alike-close/. Thank you! Thank you very much! You save my day!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem right, we wish to capture the three words, which we can start with an expression similar to:

```
^(.+?)(\s+)?({(.*)?\})?(\s+)?(.+?)?$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2j3L8/1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Emma for your help. I did not know how to express what I needed. But your example was good for me to learn a little more about regex. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**[RESOLVED]**

Thanks to [Norbert Incze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951967/norbert-incze), final regex is: **`([A-zÀ-ú]+([^\S\n]+\{[^}]*\}[^\S\n]+[A-zÀ-ú]+)+)`**

This worked perfectly! Thanks to everyone who helped me.