# Regex get only sequence of word {word} word {word} word, but not two alike close

Tags: regex

I need to get only sequence of word {word} word {word} word (ending with word and not {word}) and never two word close (word word) or two {word} next ({word} {word})

I already have this regex: https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/13

**[RESOLVED]**

Thanks to [Norbert Incze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951967/norbert-incze), in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56482610/regex-to-capture-word-word-word/), final regex is: **`([A-zÀ-ú]+([^\S\n]+\{[^}]*\}[^\S\n]+[A-zÀ-ú]+)+)`**

This worked perfectly! Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/14) what you want?

Comment: @Toto, what I need is just separate **test test**: http://prntscr.com/nywiuq. Just that. Everything else is right.

Comment: \S works for this line, but all other captured lines are harmed. Look: http://prntscr.com/nywnbg

Comment: [Updated](https://regex101.com/r/yI64KQ/15), is it valid for you? If not, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56495115/edit) and add more test cases with expected result ("should match" or "sould not match")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of updating your question, go ahead and post an answer to your question if one of the existing answers doesn't quite do it. You can then accept your own answer (after a time delay), which will let others know that your question has been solved.

Comment: Also, the most appreciate way to thank other users who provided answers that helped you is to upvote their posts. This model will help them unlock enhanced Stack Overflow features and helps other readers know which answers to pay attention to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will do as recommended. The post is not duplicate because previously I really only wanted that pattern, but later I saw that the regex needed to be improved.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my help, I did not knew that you made an another question to this topic... I think you can write the answer to your own question and accept it. :)

Comment: @Toto and @JDB, you marked this question as a duplicate, but it's not. I'm using the two regex, not just 1 (although it was possible to use only the regex `([A-zÀ-ú]+([^\S\n]+\{[^}]*\}[^S\n]+[A-zÀ-ú]+)+)`, but because it is more complex, I believe it runs in more steps unnecessarily). Why am I using the two regex? Just as an example: word1 {word} word2 {word} word3 {word} word4. Only with the other regex `((\S*[A-zÀ-ú]\s))\{.*?\}((\S[^{s]*))`, I get only word1 {word } word2 and word3 {word} word4.

Comment: With the regex `([A-zÀ-ú]+([^\S\n]+\{[^}]*\}[^\S\n]` I get only word1 {word} word2 {word} word3 {word} word4. But using the regex of this post to get everything, and the other later in javascript, I get the final result: word1 {word} word2 + **word2 {word} word3** + word3 {word} word4. This is what I need in the end, and I can only use the two regex. If it were possible to achieve this only with 1 regex would be great, but as it has not, I am using the two regex. So my questions are not identical, though they are very similar.

Comment: Is there a problem that is marked as the same question? Do you think I should delete the other one? I'm asking because I do not know what's best for Stack Overflow and for us programmers. I'm new here so I'm a bit lost as to how to proceed. If you find the questions redundant, I can delete the other question.

Answer (score 1):

The group `([^\r\n\t])+` is picking up arbitrary text until the next `{`, including whitespace and more words and even `}`. You probably want to remove it.

Inside `\{...\}`, you accept `[^}]*`, which means arbitrary characters, while what you probably want is something restrictive like your first definition of the word.

Why the last `[...]` block? I don't see what it adds given your question.

Cool web site, by the way. To make this answer make sense on its own, this is the RE you had on it when I clicked your link:

```
([A-zÀ-ú]+(\s+\{[^}]*\}\s+[A-zÀ-ú]+)([^\r\n\t])+)[^\s.:;?!]
```

Comment: Yeah, problem is `([^\r\n\t])+)`but I don't got fix it. I use `[^}]*`, because 'word' it's just an example of what is inside { }. About last block `[^\s.:;?!]` if you remove it you will see, remove space and punctuation phrases.

Comment: Well, `([^\r\n\t])+)` is certainly what's matching `test test` where you don't want it, so that's what you have to fix, there's no way around that.

Comment: I dont know how to fix. Regex is not my strong point. I tried, but I could not think of a way to solve this problem. =/

Comment: You just need to delete that block, the rest of the regex will work as is.